# Blurry logo - nav bar

Tags: html, css

My logo is showing blurry but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried removing each attribute to find what was making it blurry, but I haven't been able to figure out what's causing it.

I'm trying to get the logo to show as it does on my Figma file (first pic). I have tried with two jpgs of the logo, one 184,946 bytes (188 KB on disk) and the other 7,968 bytes (8 KB on disk), and they both look exactly the same.

[Figma logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRxoX.jpg)
[blurry logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDVOR.jpg)

```
<nav class="nav">
        <div>
            <img src="resources/img/logo.jpg" alt="Villa Csipak logo" class="nav-logo"/>
            <!-- <img src="resources/img/LOGOS/TRANSPARECIA LOGO.png" alt="Villa Csipak logo" class="logo-translucent"/> -->
            <ul class="nav-bar js--nav-bar">
                <li><a href="#the-villa">The Villa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  top: 4rem;
  height: 7.9rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid #f7f3e9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.4rem);
}

.nav-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 6.75rem;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-top: 0.375rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.775rem;
}

.nav-logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: backdrop-filter: blur(0.4rem); maybe this ?

Comment: Maybe ... `backdrop-filter: blur(0.4rem);`?

Comment: I wouldn't _assume_ that [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) is the culprit, as it is supposed to only apply to the content _behind_ the element to which it is applied, not to the elements that are contained within it.  However, it is certainly worth testing, if for nothing else than to rule it out. It would be extremely helpful if you could include a [mcve] in your question snippet (although I'm aware that it might not be possible in this scenario). Can you verify if the same thing happens with other images slotted in instead?

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing the backdrop-filter and the logo remains blurry. I'm also doing the header in codepen but I'm having trouble with some of the attributes, I'll paste the link if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the image in context, it's hard to say what the issue is. My estimation is that you are showing the image in the navbar at a higher resolution than its intrinsic width.

Give your image a `max-width` that matches its actual width.

```css
.nav-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 6.75rem;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;          /* Be explicit here */
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-top: 0.375rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.775rem;
}
```

Comment: That's not the image being blurred. It's the larger image behind, and being partially obscured by, the nav which is partially blurry. The `.nav-logo` element is fine

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the `backdrop-filter: blur(0.4rem)` is causing the blur for the logo image.

There is some explanation of how filter effects are applied to descendants/children of the parent with a backdrop-filter effect and the backdrop root here:
[Filter Effects Module Level 2 Editor’s Draft, 16 July 2020](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropRootTriggers)

> An element with a filter. Filters apply to an element and all of its
> children, rendered together. Allowing the Backdrop Root to read back
> content above a filtered element necessitates breaking the atomicity
> of the filter, with undefined results. See § 3.1 Motivation for more a
> much more detailed explanation and some examples.

A possible solution to prevent your logo from being blurred is to use a `::pseudo element` for the blur effect:

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    top: 4rem;
    height: 7.9rem;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #f7f3e9;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); /* moved */
    backdrop-filter: blur(0.4rem);  /* moved */
    z-index: -1;  /* places the blur behind the other elements */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I tried this, but it didn't work. I also tried removing the backdrop-filter altogether and it the logo is still blurry. I'll have to keep trying!

Comment: @Augusta Sorry it didn't solve the issue! You might want to check this out if you haven't already: https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052988373